# Destroying aws-ec2 instance using jclouds

Tags: jclouds

I am trying to destroy the aws-ec2 instance using jclouds (compute.destroyNode(id)). Getting the below Exception. Can any one help me how can i resolve this exception and destroy the instance. Thanks in advance

```
org.jclouds.aws.AWSResponseException: request POST https://ec2.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/ HTTP/1.1 failed with code 400, error: AWSError{requestId='2de
fa53c-fd1f-4cad-b547-4ffd2158e020', requestToken='null', code='DependencyViolation', message='resource sg-ba812bdf has a dependent object', context='{Response=,
 Errors=}'}
```

Answer (score 0):

This was actually [reported as a bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/JCLOUDS-529) in April 2014.
As of 30. Januaray 2015, this should be fixed in the versions 1.8.2+, 1.9.0+ and 2.0.0+.